# centura team developer 2.1 open same form twice

Tags: sqlbase, guptateamdeveloper, centura

I'm working in centura team developer 2.1

I have already made an app with a lot of forms. When running my app I need to open a specific form window twice at the same time.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Please ask a specific question

Comment: It's already specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open TD application and press key combination *Alt Key + Enter key* at same time for getting  *properties window*. From the properties window you have to select *Runtime tab* and make sure that the check box *Reject multiple window instances* is in unchecked state. Call your specific form window using *SalCreateWindow()* function twice.

Comment: in form properties I don't found the runtime tab !! ( notice : I'm working in TD 2.1 ) ... but I figured out another way in form menu settings ....